# ¿Cómo comparar cadenas y subcadenas que contengan espacios en c?

Tags: c

Necesito ingresar  `La vida es bella|a`  y que me imprima `La vida es bella`.

La idea es ver si existe la letra que se pone después de `|` en la primera cadena, y luego imprimirla por ejemplo `La vida es bella | o` va a imprimir que `No hay coincidencias`.

Este es mi código:

```
strcpy(subcadena,cadena);

for(i=0;i=cadena;i++){
    /*guarda la primera palabra que ingresa*/
    palabra[i] = strtok(subcadena,"|");
}

for(c=0;c=cadena;c++){
    /* guarda el fragmento*/
    fragmento[c] = strtok(NULL,"|");
}

if( strstr(palabra,fragmento) != NULL )
    printf("se encontro %s", palabra[i]);
else
    printf("No hay coincidencias\n");

}
```

Comment: Puedes dar un ejemplo mas detallado, segun entiendo tu ingresas la " La vida es bella|a" y lo que hace tu programa es que solo extrae hasta que encuentra el caracter de "|" es lo que buscas?

Comment: La idea es ver si existe la letra que se pone después | en la primera cadena. y luego imprimirla por ejemplo La vida es bella | o va a imprimir que No hay coincidencias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hola en base a la informacion proporcinada

```
int main()
{
    char mensaje[]="La vida es bella|a";
    char* pch=strstr(mensaje,"|");

    if(pch!=NULL){

        int pos=pch-mensaje+1;
        char letra=mensaje[pos];
        int i=0,flag=0;

        while(i<pos){
            if(letra==mensaje[i]){
                flag=1;
                break;
            }
            i++;
        }

        if(flag){
            printf("Se encontro la letra %c",mensaje[pos]);
        }
        else{
            printf("No se encontaron coicidencias");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```